# OllyDbg condition based on Windows Message for button click

Tags: ollydbg, breakpoint

I am attempting to set a breakpoint after a user clicks a button on a Windows GUI program.

I load the program into OllyDbg, type in `ctrl+g` to search for a function, I then use the GetMessageW function. I then set a conditional breakpoint by typing `ctrl+f4` and type in `[esp+4]` under the expression and decode the expression as a Pointer to MSGW.

All of that is working fine. Now I want to refine it so it only breaks when the Msg == WMLBUTTONDOWN for example (only when the user clicks)

Is that possible? What do I type in the conditional text box?

Answer (score 2):

MSG Structure is as below

```
typedef struct tagMSG {
   HWND hwnd;
   UINT message;
   WPARAM wParam;
   LPARAM lParam;
   DWORD time;
   POINT pt;
} MSG;
```

GetMessageAorW is as below

```
BOOL WINAPI GetMessage(
  _Out_     LPMSG lpMsg,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_      UINT wMsgFilterMin,
  _In_      UINT wMsgFilterMax
);
```

so it takes a pointer to MSG structure as its first argument ie [esp+4] is a pointer to MSG Structure

so you need to dereference [[esp+4] + 4]

ollydbg understands most of the Messages

so you can set a condition like

```
[[esp+4]+4] == WM_COMMAND
```

set pause on condition log espession on condition and log function arg on condition and hit ok

and ollydbg will break on exact message

```
Log data
Address   Message
7744CDE8  INT3: arg1 = MSGW at address 0023EB60:
                  hWnd = 00400182, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator
                  Msg = WM_COMMAND
                   = NotifyCode = MENU/BN_CLICKED..., ID = 305.
                  hControl = NULL
                  time = 114486575.
                  pt_X = 736.
                  pt_Y = 210.
7744CDE8  Call to USER32.GetMessageW from calc.002C1CB6
            0023EB60  pMsg = 0023EB60 -> MSGW {hWnd=00400182, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator, Msg=WM_COMMAND, =NotifyCode = MENU/BN_CLICKED..., ID = 305., hControl=NULL, time=114486575., pt_X=736., pt_Y=210.}
            00000000  hWnd = NULL
            00000000  MsgFilterMin = 0
            00000000  MsgFilterMax = 0
7744CDE8  Conditional breakpoint at USER32.GetMessageW
```

you can see that MSGW structure contain 111 which is WM_COMMAND

if you ask ollydbg to decode it as structure

```
Structure MSGW at 0023EB60
Address   Hex dump      Decoded data             Comments
0023EB60  /.82014000    DD      00400182         ; /hWnd = 00400182, class = CalcFrame, text = Calculator
0023EB64  |.11010000    DD      00000111         ; |Msg = WM_COMMAND
0023EB68  |.31010000    DD      00000131         ; | = NotifyCode = MENU/BN_CLICKED..., ID = 305.
0023EB6C  |.00000000    DD      00000000         ; |hControl = NULL
0023EB70  |.2FEDD206    DD      06D2ED2F         ; |time = 114486575.
0023EB74  |.E0020000    DD      000002E0         ; |pt_X = 736.
0023EB78  \.D2000000    DD      000000D2         ; \pt_Y = 210.
```

in cases where ollydbg doesnt understand some XX_YYY you can substitute hex in place of XX_YYY

```
like [[esp+4]+4] == 1337 for the condition statement
```

[image]